# HackyViewPager in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to convert this HackyViewPager for PhotoView into a version for Xamarin.Android, but I can't now wrap my head around on how to.

Here is the HackyViewPager class that extends ViewPager

```
public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isLocked;

    public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        isLocked = false;
    }

    public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        isLocked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            try {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void toggleLock() {
        isLocked = !isLocked;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean isLocked) {
        this.isLocked = isLocked;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return isLocked;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to convert java into C# like the following

```
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Content;
using Java.Lang;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;

public class HackyViewPager : ViewPager
{

    private bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public HackyViewPager (Context context)
        : base (context)
    {
        IsLocked = false;
    }

    public HackyViewPager (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base (context, attrs)
    {
        IsLocked = false;
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (!IsLocked) {
            try {
                return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent (ev);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (!IsLocked) {
            return base.OnTouchEvent (ev);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void ToggleLock ()
    {
        IsLocked = !IsLocked;
    }

}
```